# Getting http status code

Tags: python

Is there any way to get http status in non-numeric way. Like if I use http module   I get http.HTTPStatus.ok which is numeric form of 200. However, I would like to get it as http.HTTPStatus.ok only in alphbetic way for comparision.

I am using a python code which executes an url and get the result back and result.response_code is http.HTTPStatus.ok.

Comment: Probably not - the status code is a code returned by the web server - anything more then that would require additional parsing, which you may as well do yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html):

```
>>> import http
>>> http.HTTPStatus.OK.phrase
'OK'
```

Based on what you've written you should therefore be able to do something like `result.response_code.phrase`. If instead you get a **number** back you can reverse the lookup like this:

```
>>> http.HTTPStatus(200).phrase
'OK'
```